# Where can I find the SimpleITK documentation and reference information?

Tags: itk, simpleitk

I am interested in trying to use SimpleITK to solve my imaging problem.  Can you please tell me where the documentation and training materials are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SimpleITK is documented [here](http://www.itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/annotated.html), and has a [tutorial](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK-MICCAI-2011-Tutorial) that has been presented at the MICCAI 2011 conference.

Development of SimpleITK is [hosted on Github](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK) and [feature requests can be entered in Jira.](https://issues.itk.org/jira/browse/SIMPLEITK)

**Direct Links:**

- https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK-MICCAI-2011-Tutorial
- https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK
- http://www.simpleitk.org

Answer (score 4):

There are additional resources that are useful, SimpleITK's WIKI, SimpleITK-Notebooks, and SimpleITK Doxygen.

The [SimpleITK WIKI](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK) contains a FAQ, information on building SimpleITK, and some visual guides to getting started in different languages.

[SimpleITK-Notebooks](http://simpleitk.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/) is a collection of Python Notebooks containing examples on how to do image processing.

[SimpleITK's Doxygen](http://www.itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classes.html) contains documentation of the C++ API, along with basic example for different languages.

Comment: I would say the SimpleITK-Notebooks listed above are the best place for a beginner to start after having installed SimpleITK.

Answer (score 3):

Not documentation, but Kyriakou's PyScience blog has excellent and in-depth implementations of SimpleITK and VTK.

For SimpleITK he goes over

- Image segmentation (https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/image-segmentation-with-python-and-simpleitk/#more-126)
- Multi-modal segmentation (https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/multi-modal-image-segmentation-with-python-simpleitk/)