# Transferring between numerical arrays and SimpleITK Image objects

Tags: java, wrapper, itk

I am trying to use the Java SimpleITK wrapper for medical image processing.

I need to do some manipulation of the image as a plain numerical array before and after leveraging the ITK segmentation filters.  However, I can't find an efficient way of either transferring a numerical array to an SITK Image object or reverting an Image object back to a numerical array.  Using nested loops to do a per-pixel `setPixelAs` or `getPixelAs` operation takes an inordinate amount of time.

I understand the `getPixelContainer` method is now deprecated (?) and was supposed to be replaced by the `getBufferAs` methods, which I can see in the Doxygen Image class listing but seem to be suppressed in the Java wrapper (v0.6.1).  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now being discussed here:
http://itk-users.7.n7.nabble.com/Why-are-getBufferAs-methods-not-available-in-Java-td30969.html

It seems that Java doesn't yet have such an easy wrapper while python can use SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage(image_obj). I see an issue in 2011 here: https://issues.itk.org/jira/browse/SIMPLEITK-40.

It might be worth considering whether you need to wrap this in Java or whether you can wrap it some other way (C++?)

Also, have a look at the various sources of documentation nicely collated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7521426/607562).